# Infinitely many positive integers of the form $1998k+1$ such that all digits in their decimal representation are equal

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that there exist infinitely many positive integers of the form $1998k+1, k \in \mathbb{N},$ such that all digits in their decimal representation are equal.

We need to find integer solutions to $a \cdot \dfrac{10^n-1}{9} = 1998k+1$. Thus $$a(10^n-1) = 9(1998k+1).$$ How can we find infinitely many integer solutions to this?

Comment: @mdave16 more like $1998 = 2\times 3^3\times 37$

Comment: while $a$ lives between $1$ and $9$, there are infinitely many values for $n$, but using the factorisation, you can figure out what values of $a$ work. @user19405892

Comment: Let's use $111...11$. We need $111...10$ to be divisible by $1998=2\times 3^3\times 37$. Let us assume that the number of $1$ in $111...10$ is multiple of 4. Since $1000 = 1$ both mod 27 and mod 37 then $111...10$ is equal to $1111m$ mod both $27$ and $37$, where $m$ is the number of blocks of 1111 in the number. If we take m to be multiple of both 27 and 37 then 111...10 will be multiple of both 27 and 37, as well as 2.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy Quick check, $11110 \not\equiv 1111\pmod{27}$ and $111111110 \not\equiv 2222\pmod{37}$.

Comment: @peterwhy 11110 has only one block of 1111, so (m=1). 1 is not multiple of 27

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy I am talking about "Since $1000=1$ both mod 27 and mod 37 then $111\ldots10$ is equal to $1111m$ mod both 27 and 37, where $m$ is the number of blocks of $1111$ in the number." The deduction in this sentence is flawed.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy The correct deduction would be to assume that the number of $1$ in $111\ldots1110$ is a multiple of 3. Since $1000 \equiv 1$ both mod 27 and mod 37 then $111\ldots10 \equiv 1110m$ mod both 27 and 37, where $m$ is the number of blocks of $111$ in the number. If you agree with this, I encourage you to write a full answer below.

Comment: @peterwhy That's right. I miscounted again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit of the full answer to Mlazhinka Shung Gronzalez LeWy.

Let $N = 10^{3n} - 1 = 999\ldots 9$. By factorisation, $N$ is a multiple of $999$, and the other quotient is $$\frac{10^{3n}-1}{10^3-1} = 10^{3(n-1)}+ \cdots + 10^6 + 10^3+1.$$

I further would like the quotient be a multiple of $9$, so that $N$ is a multiple of $999\times 9$. Since $10\equiv 1\pmod 9$, the right hand side

$$10^{3(n-1)}+ \cdots + 10^6 + 10^3+1 \equiv n \pmod 9$$

So $n$ can be any multiple of $9$, i.e. $N = 10^{27m}-1$. Let 
$$\begin{align*}
M = \frac N9 &= \frac{10^{27m}-1}{9}\\
10M &=\frac{10^{27m+1}-1}{9}-1
\end{align*}$$

$M$ is a multiple of $999$, and so $10M$ is a multiple of $999$, and so

$$\frac{10^{27m+1}-1}{9}\equiv 1 \pmod{999}$$

But the left hand side is just $10^{27m} + 10^{27m-1} + \cdots + 10^2+10^1+10^0$, which is odd, 
$$\frac{10^{27m+1}-1}{9}\equiv 1 \pmod{2}$$

By Chinese remainder theorem,
$$\frac{10^{27m+1}-1}{9}\equiv 1 \pmod{1998}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_t$ be a number whose decimal expansion has $t$ $1$ digits, e.g. $a_7=1111111$. Note that for $i>j$, $a_i-a_j=a_{i-j}*10^j$, e.g $a_5-a_2=11111-11=11100=a_3\times 10^2$.

**Proposition:**
Let $n=2m$ where $m$ is any odd number not divisible by $5$. Then among the numbers $nk+1$, k=1,2,3,... there are infinitely many $a_t$ numbers.

For $m=999, n=1998$ this proposition answers the question.

**Proof:**
The set of remainders of the numbers $a_t$ by $m$,
$$R=\{a_t \mod m : t=1,2,3,...\}$$
is a finite set (whose cardinality is at most $m$), and so there exists $T$ such that 
$$R=\{a_t \mod m : t=1,2,3,..,T \}$$
Now take the numbers $a_{2T},a_{3T},a_{4T},..$. For each $a_{iT}$ there exists $a_{s_i}$, $1<=s_i<=T$, such that $a_{iT} \equiv a_{s_i} \mod m$. Therefore $m$ divides $a_{iT}-a_{s_i}$. But 
$$a_{iT}-a_{s_i}=a_{iT-s_i} \times 10^{s_i}$$
Since neither $2$ nor $5$ divide m, it follows that m divides $a_{iT-s_i}$, and thus $n=2m$ divides $a_{iT-s_i} \times 10$. So for some $k_i$
$$a_{iT-s_i} \times 10 + 1 = n\times k_i +1 $$
But $a_{iT-s_i} \times 10 + 1$ is just $a_{iT-s_i+1}$. So for each $i = 2,3,..$, there exist $s_i \in {1,..,T}$, and $k_i$ such that
$$a_{iT-s_i+1} = nk_i + 1$$
Since for any $i \neq j$ we have $a_{iT-s_i+1} \neq a_{jT-s_j+1}$, this proves the proposition.